How to Read a Value as a Specific Data Type (Float instead of UINT16) Using Python OPC-UA Client?
Screen Shot From the OPC QUICK CLIENT
I am working with the Python OPC-UA client to retrieve values from an OPC UA server. I've encountered a challenge where I need to ensure that I fetch these values as floats. Using the OPC Quick Client, I confirmed that the server stores values in various data types, including float, so it is indeed possible to read them as such.
However, I am struggling to fetch the value as a float directly using the Python OPC-UA library. Here's what I've tried:
Calling get_value() without specifying the data type, which does not guarantee fetching the value as a float.
I tried specifying a data type directly in the get_value() method call (as get_value(datatype=ua.VariantType.Float)), but received an error that get_value() does not accept a 'datatype' argument.
Here's the code snippet I'm working with:
from opcua import Client
import logging
from opcua import ua

# Setup logging to debug level
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

url = "opc.tcp://xxx:1111"
client = Client(url)

try:
    client.connect()
    print("Client connected to:", url)

    node_id = "ns=2;s=xxx_lf_V.Rpc.30043"
    node = client.get_node(node_id)
    current_value = node.get_value()
    print("Current value from node:", current_value)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error accessing node {node_id}: {str(e)}")

finally:
    client.disconnect()
    print("Client disconnected")

Given that the server does store values as floats, how can I correctly fetch these values as floats using the Python OPC-UA client? Please, see the attached photo that shows that I indeed was able to fetch the same register in different datatypes using the quick client app. Any help or suggestions on how to handle this correctly would be greatly appreciated!
how to exactly fetch the value from the OPC server in a different datatype to what I am currently getting

Eh? Float is 32 bits. Uint16 is 16 bits.

You need to combine registers using the struct module. This answer has an example.

I guess being a mechanical engineer and jumping into automation/programming won't be easy. Thank you guys! the above really worked.

You can answer your own question to assist future struggling mechanical engineers and their ilk.
